# How to call a parent class's function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclass

I have a parent class with a function. There is a subclass of the parent class that has the same function name, but instead of overriding it as usual, I would like to call the parent's function as well.

Here is an example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p
    def printp(self):
        print(self.p)

class Bob(Person):
    def printp(self):
        print('letter')
        
b = Bob('p')
b.printp()
```

Currently, this prints 'p'. I would like it to print:

```
p
letter
```

Comment: Add a `super().printp()` at the top of `Person.printp`

Answer (score 0):

**This could be one solution:**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p
    def printp(self):
        print(self.p)

class Bob(Person):
    def printp(self):
        # here I use super to call parent class printp()
        super().printp()
        print('letter')
        
b = Bob('p')
b.printp()
```

**Output:**

```
p
letter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the parent's method from the child's method like so:

```
class Bob(Person):
    def printp(self):
        super().printp()
        print('letter')
```